# What is the most recent documentation for C#?

Tags: c#, .net, documentation, msdn

I was searching the Internet many times looking for C# documentation and references and many times I stumbled upon old archived MSDN sites. I've recently found this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kx37x362.aspx and believed that It's the most actual version but a while ago I searched "C# Threads" and found another Microsoft website https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/articles/csharp/index not even included in MSDN. Now I have like 5-6 different sources for C# documentation and I don't know which is the most recent and best to use. I am confused with all these websites, all are official Microsoft sources and I don't know which to use.

Could you tell me guys which one do you use mostly and recommend as the main source of information about the language?

Comment: they have deleted my answer. Here is a link to the C# language spec, which is what you are looking for - https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft is migrating contents from MSDN and TechNet to Docs, so you should be able to find and suggest new things at

http://learn.microsoft.com